# Conventions for fortran90 or gfortran - Declaration of integer, real, double and array

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran, fortran90, variable-declaration

I would like to get clarifications about the declaration in Fortran90 or gfortran.

Firstly, for declaring integer and double, it seems that convention is:

```
! i is an integer
integer::i
```

whereas I have also seen a simple declaration like (in my code, I use this one):

```
! i is an integer
integer i
```

i.e, without the '`::`' symbol.

What is the norm about this declaration (for `integer, real, double`)?

Is it the same for declaring arrays ? i.e, is symbol '`::`' necessary like in this following declaration:

```
! declaration of array "list" with 10 elements
double precision,dimension(10)::list
```

I looked for a simpler declaration for array, without success.

Finally, I also use the following syntax for allocatable arrays:

```
! Arrays 
double precision, allocatable :: x(:,:)
! Allocation of 2D Array
allocate(x(1:size_x,1:size_y))
```

Is it a recent way (I mean a recent convention or norm in Fortran) to declare allocatable array?

PS: I don't know very well the evolution of different versions for Fortran (for example the differences between `fortran90` and `gfortran`.

Comment: Fortran90 (like FORTRAN77, Fortran2003, Fortran2008) is a version while gfortran(GNU Fortran) is a compiler (like ifort -Intel Fortran-, pgfortran -PGI Fortran- ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a variable declaration, `::` is required for one of two reasons:

- there is an attribute list in the declaration statement;
- there is explicit initialization in the statement.

For the first we see such as

```
integer, dimension(5) :: i
integer, target :: j
```

For the second

```
integer :: k=1
```

It isn't harmful to use `::` when optional/not required.  Although the token isn't valid in Fortran standards before F90.

Finally, note that `integer i(5)` doesn't require the `::`.  I've seen advice given to use `::` always for consistency and saving effort learning/applying the rules.

Comment: Could you mention something about the difference between vendors and versions of the standard, regarding the OP's final question?

Comment: No, I think the OP is confusing gfortran and fortran 90. One is a vendor, the other is refers to a Fortran standard. Or perhaps they aren't sure what standards gfortran suppports? @youpilat13 might need to clarify.

Comment: @francescalus I asked this question because I use compiler "mpif90", i.e MPI (Message Passing Interface) library in fortran, so I concluded that I had to respect fortran90 conventions. As a conclusion and with what I say above, do you advice me to set or unset "`::`" for array declarations ?

Comment: In each of your two array examples, @youpilat13, the `::`s are mandatory.  This follows from the attribute items.  You could phrase the first as `double precision list(10)` without (and I probably would - except using `real(..)`) but this is largely style and personal preference.

Comment: As a style preference, I suggest always using the :: whether or not it is necessary. The style without the :: is from FORTRAN 77 and older - it still works if all you're doing is declaring the type, but is "old fashioned".